# Could not load library libcublasLt.so.12. Error: libcublasLt.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, Conv2D TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow2.0, wsl-2

I am trying to setup TensorFlow with GPU support in WSL2. I am following [this](https://medium.com/@xizengmao/install-tensorflow-with-gpu-acceleration-simultaneously-for-windows-and-wsl-linux-2-10da088d5e4f) guide.

When I run this code:

```
>>> from tensorflow import keras
>>> import numpy as np
>>> t = np.ones([5,32,32,3])
>>> c = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu")
>>> c(t)
```

I get this error:

```
2023-07-09 09:59:38.820408: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-07-09 09:59:39.031437: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-07-09 09:59:39.031864: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-07-09 09:59:39.034068: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-07-09 09:59:39.034535: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-07-09 09:59:39.034921: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-07-09 09:59:40.590457: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-07-09 09:59:40.590941: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-07-09 09:59:40.591052: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1722] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU id 0, defaulting to 0.  Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2023-07-09 09:59:40.591459: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-07-09 09:59:40.591526: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1635] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3858 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
Could not load library libcublasLt.so.12. Error: libcublasLt.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Aborted
```

The confusing thing is that when I run this code:

```
>>> from tensorflow import keras
>>> import numpy as np
>>> t = np.ones([5,32,32,3])
>>> c = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu")
>>> c(t)
```

I get an output and no errors.

- I have tried reinstalling Cuda, CuDNN
- I have tried installing everything in a fresh install of wsl ubuntu 20.04 & 22.04.2
- I have tried Tensorflow 2.10, 2.11, 2.12 and 2.13
- I also tried `apt install libcublasLt`

Nothing worked

Environment:

- Windows 11 Home
- WSL 2
- Intel i7-9750h
- Nvidia RTX 2060 Notebook
- Tensorflow 2.12.1
- Python 3.9
- WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04
- Cuda 11.8
- CuDNN 8.6

I am also running it in a conda evironment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like you, I was using TensorFlow with CUDA 11 when I suddenly started to see these errors asking for CUDA 12 libraries.

After searching a little I found that the `libcublas-12-0` Ubuntu package does provide all the required files:

```
/usr/local/cuda-12.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/
 libcublas.so.12 -> libcublas.so.12.0.2.224
 libcublasLt.so.12 -> libcublasLt.so.12.0.2.224
 libnvblas.so.12 -> libnvblas.so.12.0.2.224
```

However, I did not want to mess up my perfectly fine CUDA 11 installation, so I just manually downloaded the package and extracted the required files into the current CUDA directory:

```bash
# install CUDA repo: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#network-repo-installation-for-ubuntu
sudo apt update
sudo apt download libcublas-12-0
mkdir contents
dpkg-deb -xv libcublas-12-0_<VERSION>_<ARCH>.deb contents/
sudo mv contents/usr/local/cuda-12.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/* /usr/local/cuda/lib64/
rm -rf contents
```

Still no clue why TensorFlow needs these libraries in the first place ...

Comment: This worked as expected

Comment: Worked like a charm, BUT also had to run a `sudo ldconfig` to detect changes

Answer (score 3):

Installing the CUDA 12 version of libcublas worked for me, per [this discussion](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/which-subpackage-of-tensorflow-loads-libcublaslt-so/17547).

```
sudo apt-get install libcublas-12-0
```